# sound driver - snd-aloop kernel module setup issue with AWS EC2 ubuntu 16.04 instance

Tags: ubuntu, audio, amazon-ec2, kernel, kernel-module

Unable to use snd-aloop audio driver in AWS EC2 ubuntu 16.04 instance

On running modprobe on snd-aloop

```
$modprobe snd-aloop
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1052-aws
```

Kernels in AWS matchine are -

```
/lib/modules/4.4.0-1049-aws  
/lib/modules/4.4.0-1052-aws  
/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic
```

Current kernel loaded

```
$uname -r
4.4.0-1052-aws
```

1. After searching a lot it was confirmed that snd-aloop comes pre-installed in ubuntu 16.04.(https://askubuntu.com/questions/891445/alsa-snd-aloop-kernel-module-for-16-04-or-14-04-server)
2. So i verified and found that the module was present at

> "/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic" kernel. location - /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko

1. After giving much thought one possible way to use snd-aloop audio driver was
   to use 4.4.0.116-generic kernel.

   - So to do the same i modified **/boot/grub/menu.lst** and edited the **kernel
     list**.(commented out all other kernels other then 4.4.0.116-generic)
     and then did update-grub but nothing happened, kernel loaded was
     /lib/modules/4.4.0-1052-aws.
   - Then i modified the **/etc/default/grub file** and 
     changed **GRUB_DEFAULT=0** to kernel title as 
     **GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-4.4.0-116-generic-advanced-b6adc449-5e3d-4331-ba6b-6e99a75fa48e>gnulinux-4.4.0-116-generic-recovery-b6adc449-5e3d-4331-ba6b-6e99a75fa48e"**
     and again did an grub update but again nothing happened.

I have already gone through the following doc's

1.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html - Aws doc guide to change kernels.

I can't recall the other links but i have searched a lot.

Please point me in the right direction. How can i use audio driver sdn-aloop in AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Steps to update default kernel boot item (without modification of **/boot/grub/menu.lst**):

1. Find needed menu and sub-menu item in **grub.cfg**:
   `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

   For example you can have menu structure like this (default for **AWS Ubuntu 16.04**):

   - (0) Ubuntu
   - (1) Advanced options for Ubuntu

     - (0) Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws
     - (1) Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1052-aws (recovery mode)
     - (2) Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
     - (3) Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-116-generic (recovery mode)

   In this case if you need to load "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-116-generic" your default boot setting would be "1>2"
2. Edit default grub file:

   `vim /etc/default/grub` and set

   `GRUB_DEFAULT=“1>2”`
3. Run `update-grub`
4. And then `reboot now` to take this in effect
5. After reboot you can test it with `uname -a` which should give **4.4.0-116-generic**

After this `modprobe snd-aloop` should work fine.

Comment: Hi. I followed the directions. In ubuntu 18. without success

Comment: @websquared, Thanks!. This worked for me for aws ubuntu 18.04

Comment: My EC2 instance only comes with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-1023-aws` and `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-1023-aws (recovery mode)`, thus this does not work.

Comment: Working for 18.04 but not for Ubuntu 20.04. What changed from one to the other?

Answer (score 5):

Jibri on AWS and getting the below issue.

> org.jitsi.jibri.capture.ffmpeg.FfmpegCapturer.onFfmpegProcessUpdate() Ffmpeg quit abruptly. Last output line: plug:bsnoop: Input/output error

**Solution:** changing and updating the kernel boot settings from Linux 4.4.0-xxxx-aws to Linux 4.4.0-xxxx-generic and restarting the instance.

I have fixed by the following steps:

> $ grep -A200 submenu  /boot/grub/grub.cfg |grep menuentry

**Output:**

```
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1107-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1107-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1107-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1107-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1106-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1106-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1106-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1106-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1105-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1105-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1105-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1105-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
```

menu entry id for Advanced options for Ubuntu is gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1
menu entry for Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic is gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1

**Edit Grub** and replace GRUB_DEFAULT with above value

> $ nano /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1>gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**Update and Reboot**

> $ sudo update-grub
>   $ sudo reboot

After reboot you can test it with uname -a which should give 4.4.0-179-generic

> $ uname -a

Linux 4.4.0-179-generic

After this modprobe snd-aloop should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

How i did this was run

`grep-A100 submenu  /boot/grub/grub.cfg |grep menuentry`

This lists something like

`submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-1017-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-1017-aws-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-1017-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-1017-aws-recovery-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-1065-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-1065-aws-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-1065-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-1065-aws-recovery-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-99-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-99-generic-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-99-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-99-generic-recovery-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187' {`

So chose the first menuentryid i.e. gnulinux-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187 and the generic id gnulinux-4.15.0-99-generic-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187

THen join them with > which will look like this

gnulinux-4.15.0-99-generic-recovery-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187>gnulinux-4.15.0-99-generic-advanced-6156ec80-9446-4eb1-95e0-9ae6b7a46187

and set this as GRUB_DEFAULT value as above then update-grub and reboot. You should get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 AMIs use aws ubuntu kernel modules instead of the ubuntu generic modules, *which omits alsa sound drivers*

snd-dummy and other alsa drivers were added to the `linux-modules-extras` for Ubuntu Jammy (22.04).

So you will need to use a base ami with this version of ubuntu or later.

To install the extra modules you can run this command:

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

After that you can do modprob and modinfo on snd-dummy